# How to boot Raspberry 3b from SSD?

Tags: pi-3, usb, boot, boot-issues, home-automation

I have

- [Raspberry Pi 3b v1.2](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32617596319.html?sku_id=59338429172)
- [Smartbuy Splash 128GB SBSSD-128GT-MX902-25S3](https://smartbuy-russia.ru/product/ssd_hdd/2507/26123/)
- [SATA to USB 2.0 cable](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005002532708733.html?sku_id=12000026754121876)

I would like to boot Home Assistant OS ([img](https://github.com/home-assistant/operating-system/releases/download/9.5/haos_rpi3-64-9.5.img.xz)) from SSD. The same system boots well from SD card.

I have enabled the usb boot by adding `program_usb_boot_mode=1` to config.txt and rebooting the device.

The raspberry still doesn't boot from SSD (the SATA-USB cable led is switched on for a second and then switched off).

I've placed [the latest bootcode.bin](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#special-bootcode-bin-only-boot-mode) to SD card and was able to boot from SSD once or twice. Once fully powered off, I can not boot again.

I tried the following:

1. added `timeout` file to SSD. With this file the SATA-USB cable led is switched on constantly. Raspberry Pi led is red.
2. added `program_usb_boot_mode=1` to `config.txt` again.
3. added `program_usb_boot_timeout=1` to `config.txt`. With this config Raspberry Pi led blinks yellow.

What else should I try?

Upd. `lsusb` result when booted from SSD (Home Assistant) with SD card inserted:
[image: lsusb result]
Upd2. I have bought another sata-to-usb cable. Here is the output:
[image: lsusb second result]

Comment: boot using SD with the SSD attached. run `lsusb` and post the results in the question. guessing it's a jmicron USB to SATA device, which have issues - `Raspberry Pi led blinks yellow.` there is no yellow LED

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks. I've added `lsusb` output. Not sure about LED color. Is it green?)

Comment: why have you cropped `lsusb` output FFS - `when booted from SSD` - thought you couldn't boot from SSD

Comment: @JaromandaX, this is the full output (I used Terminal of Home Assistant OS). The boot works sometimes. Now it is booted from SSD and I am afraid to power it off ;)

Comment: ahh, my apologies, didn't realise home assistants lsusb was so crippled - anyway, looking up 14cd:6116 the likely USB->SATA device seems like a poor device to use - get a better one

Comment: @JaromandaX, I got another device. Is `152d:2329` better? It boots well, but Raspberry Pi unexpectedly reboots with this device.

Comment: are you sure it's this devices fault?

Comment: @JaromandaX, looks like it is not :). Thanks for your help. 

How do you know if the device is good or poor?

Comment: can you show the text you've hidden from `lsusb` - i.e. the device description

Comment: @JaromandaX since this is Home Assistant OS, there is no more any hidden output from lsusb, this is all.

Comment: Oh well that's annoying (I forgot you said that last week) - try getting your hands on a ugreen cable then - they've never failed me